# HTML5 video source changing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-video

I have a video tag like this. All this videos have to play dynamically one after other
I tried writing some javascript functions in eventlistner "progress" of the video, but not working.How to play these videos automatically?anybody please suggest any codes in javascript or jquery

```
<div id="divVid">
            <video id="video1" width="320" height="240" autoplay >
               <source src="vid_future technology_n.mp4#t=20,50" >            
               Your browser does not support the video tag.
            </video>
    </div>
```

JS Code (Updated from comment section)

```
document.getElementById("video1")
.addEventListener("progress", 
  function () { 
   var i = 0; 
   var vid = document.getElementById("video1"); 
    if (vid.paused) { 
     if (vid.currentSrc == myvids[i]) { 
       vid.currentSrc = myvids[i + 1]; } i = i + 1; 
    } 
});
```

Comment: Add your JS code also

Comment: Murali, 
document.getElementById("video1").addEventListener("progress", function () {
            var i = 0;
            var vid = document.getElementById("video1");
            if (vid.paused) {
                if (vid.currentSrc == myvids[i]) {
                    vid.currentSrc = myvids[i + 1];
                }
                i = i + 1;
            }
        });

Answer (score 3):

The set of `<source>` elements provide *alternative* formats for the video for different devices, not a playlist.

If you want to have a playlist, then [listen](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener) for an [ended event](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#mediaevents) and change the `src` with JavaScript.

---

In response to edits to the question:

- No, really change the `src`. You are trying to change the `currentSource` which is defined as being *readonly*
- I said `ended`. Don't touch `progress`, you what to play the next video when the last one is finished, not when a tiny chunk of it has played
- The list of `<source>` elements still isn't a playlist. Don't try to use them as such. Keep the list of videos somewhere else (e.g. a JS array).

Comment: document.getElementById("video1")[0].addEventListener("ended", function () {         
            alert("ended");
        });

alert is not working at all as the first video is stopped

Comment: `document.getElementById("video1")` will (if an element with that id exists) give you an HTMLElementNode. It won't give you an array or a NodeList, so you shouldn't expect it to have a `0` property. Doesn't that like of code throw an error in your JS console?

Comment: document.getElementById("video1").addEventListener("ended", function () {          
            alert("ended");
        });

still not working

Comment: Works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/bxf35/ (token for Dropbox might expire. Change the URL to a video of your own if the video doesn't play at all).

Comment: The video is from my file system,with in the project folder of mine.
Can u pls share ur code here.

Comment: My code is copy/pasted from your question and previous comment! I just put it in the form of a live demo.